# How can I make this image merge into this vertical line hiding part of the image?

Tags: html, css

[image]

I want to see how to make the image, which is the globe to hide part of itself behind the line.

```
 <div class="verticalLine" >
 <img src="/icons/globe.png" alt="globe" />
 </div>
 .verticalLine {
border-right: 2px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `overflow: hidden;` property and a certain `width` on the `div.verticalLine`.

Example [here](http://jsbin.com/zonozefudo/1/edit?html,css,output).

Answer (score 0):

```
.verticalLine { 
  border-right: 2px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: If your answer is just "try this", it is not an answer. It is a comment. To write a useful answer, please add description.